# Showing a series has radius of convergence $1$ and finding a closed form for its sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, binomial-theorem

> Show that the series $\sum_{l \ge k}\binom{l} {k} z^{l-k}$ has radius of convergence equal $1$. And find a closed form for its sum.

**My attempt:**

$$\binom{l} {k} = \frac{l!}{k!(l-k)!}$$

Let $a_l = \frac{l!}{k!(l-k)!}$
And so lim as $l$ tends to infinity of $\frac{a_{l+1}}{a_l} = 1$.

And hence $R=1$

And a closed form will be $(1+z)^l$. Are my answers correct? Any help please?

Comment: I would think that $k$ is fixed and you are supposed  to sum over  $l$. You are doing the reverse when you derived a the closed form.

Comment: I didn't understand

Comment: It seems that $l,k$ are integers and $\sum_{l \ge k}\binom{l} {k} z^{l-k} = \sum_{l =k}^\infty \binom{l} {k} z^{l-k}$ Thus the closed form should depend on $k$ and not on $l$.